# How can I visualize XML in Flex /Flash?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, flash, visualization, data-visualization

I'm making a Flex application to visualize the contents of an XML file in a tree, radial diagram, etc... I looked all over the internet and I can't find any useful tutorials or source code on how to do this. Most existing components on the web have licensing issues with them, so I prefer to write some sort of XML visualization algorithm from scratch.

An example I found was [ScienceLogic](http://www.cynergytv.com/#video=sciLogic&page=1). This is very similar to what I am trying to do.

Any help on how I can write an XML/data visualizer in Flex/Flash? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:
The visualizer should make something like a hierarchy diagram, like so:

```
SERVER 1
  -Unit 1
  -Unit 2
     -Unit 3
  -Unit 4
```

Think of a network with servers and routers and computers - and you want to put that in a web or diagram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/). Take a look at their demo for radial layouts, that might be what you're looking for, though it's not as glamorous as ScienceLogic, it is free.

Answer (score 1):

[Axiis](http://www.axiis.org/) is another visualization framework based off Degrafa. Very nice. That and [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/) are the best open solutions I've seen to date.